# Find if notifications are disabled on lock screen by the user

Tags: android, android-notifications

In Android there is an option to choose how notifications will show on the lock screen:

1. Show all notification content.
2. Hide sensitive content.
3. Don't show notifications at all.

In phones that run stock Android OS the lock screen preferences are global for all the apps. But in Xiaomi it is possible to configure these preferences for each app.

Is there a way I can programmatically find out from my android app if the user selected to opt out from notifications on lock screen?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Hi rekire
i did not find a solution back than.

Comment: I found one as you can see in the Answer section :-D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this works on all Android versions, but this works for me:

```
fun getLockscreenNotificationsEnabled(context: Context) =
    android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(
        context.contentResolver,
        "lock_screen_show_notifications", 0
    ) != 0
```